# WPF- How Can I Show a Cropped Region of an ImageSource in an <Image> Control?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, crop, imagesource

WPF- How can I show a cropped region of an ImageSource in an  control?

I have an ImageSource of a vairable size in pixels. I have a caculated crop rectangle, indicating how much of the image we are actually going to use. I don't want to edit the image data directly, but I want my `<Image>` control to display only the cropped region of the ImageSource.

Does Microsoft provide a way to automate this?
Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [CroppedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752345.aspx).

Here is an example of its usage:

```
   <Page.Resources>
      <!-- Define some image resources, for use as the image element source. -->
      <BitmapImage x:Key="masterImage" UriSource="/sampleImages/gecko.jpg" />
      <CroppedBitmap x:Key="croppedImage" 
         Source="{StaticResource masterImage}" SourceRect="30 20 105 50"/>
   </Page.Resources>
```